# I want to give box shadow to the Header according to below in image in React native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to give box shadow to Header according to below in image in React native navigation and after giving borderBottomRadius there is a little white color showing from both right and left side i want to remove that color and want to make that according to the home.js background color.

here is code of header:

```
const stackNav = createStackNavigator({
Home : {
  screen: Routes.Home,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: "Home",
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: '600',
      color: '#e91e63',
    },
    headerStyle:{
      borderBottomLeftRadius:10,
      borderBottomRightRadius:10,
    },
    headerLeft:(<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
                  <View style={{
                    paddingLeft: 15
                  }}>
                    <IOSIcon
                      name="ios-menu"
                      size={40}
                      color='#e91e63'
                    />
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  })
}
});
```

here is Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View,Text, StyleSheet,Dimensions } from 'react-native';

class Home extends React.Component {


render() {
return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Home.js</Text>
    </View>
)
}
}

export default Home;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
    backgroundColor:'#F0F3F5',
    flex:1,
}
})
```

what i want in header the box shadow
[image: what i want in header the box shadow]

want to get rid of that mark area or change color according to Home.js color
[image: want to get rid of that mark area or change color according to Home.js color]

Comment: Tried adding backgroundColor?

Comment: You should add your style code so we see what you are doing. From your attached image, the white background you are seeing is from the parent container. you can fix it by reducing the top margin of the main container till is covers up the space. eg `{marginTop: '-15px' }`

Comment: @AfiaUdofia isn't it a bad practice?

Comment: It depends on your usage. Better if you can change the background color of the parent container to match your Home view background color.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code, the best we can do is guess.

Maybe you're adding the box-shadow to the parent container (wrapper) instead of the white rounded 'plate'?